# WebApi2 odata - client, with ability to retrieve 'All data pages'

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I tried creating a default odata v3 client in Visual studio by adding a service reference, and it works fine.

[image]
I noticed that by default - VS uses `System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery` class, which is not able to navigate through odata data page's (assuming the service returns data in pages of 50 items)

I noticed there's a very similar class but in a different namespace, and was wondering (having trouble) of actually making use of it.

[image]

Looking for guidance / ideas / samples / snippets - on how to actually make use of this ?

The goal - is to iterate over odata data collection, and have it load data as you enumerate over it

Answer (score 0):

Here's how

```
var ctx = new Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext(
                        new Uri("https://dev.santa.lt/svcext/medpas/api/v0.1/odata/"), 
                        ODataProtocolVersion.V4);

var q = ctx.CreateQuery<Specialybe>("Specialybes").GetAllPages();
```